# Unable to Call Web Api from Winform (Bad Request ERROR)

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I am trying to call An API from winform Application, But I am getting the bad request error. I think I couldn't format the valid string for my post request.

**Edit** Adding driverDayLogModel Class Code

driveDayLogModel.cs

```
public class driverDayLogModel
{
    public int driverId { get; set; }
    public DateTime dayStartTime { get; set; }
}
```

API calling code

```
driverDayLogModel driverDayLog = new driverDayLogModel
{
    driverId = Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text),
    dayStartTime = DateTime.Now,
};
var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(driverDayLog);
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:54314/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/driverdaylogs", json).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // Some Stuff
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error Code" +
        response.StatusCode + " : Message - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
    }
}
```

I am getting Json As `"{\"driverId\":1,\"dayStartTime\":\"2019-03-03T21:44:15.1912313+05:00\"}"`
Which seems a not valid json for the API, when I try with same json on postman it also resulting 400 Bad Request Error, But it must be noted that When I call API with the Json `{"driverId":1,"dayStartTime":"2019-03-03T21:44:15.1912313+05:00"}` My request goes succesful to API, and I got expected response in POSTMAN. I am unable to convert the json into acceptable format for the webapi in winforms

Following is the code for Webapi.

```
public IHttpActionResult PostDayLogs([FromBody]driverDayLogModel log)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    var driverDayLog = new driverDailyLogs();
    driverDayLog.dayEndTime = DateTime.Now;
    driverDayLog.dayStartTime = log.dayStartTime;
    driverDayLog.driverId = log.driverId;
    var max = db.driverDailyLogs.OrderByDescending(r => r.id).FirstOrDefault();
    driverDayLog.id = max == null ? 1 : max.id + 1;
    driverDayLog.logDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
    db.driverDailyLogs.Add(driverDayLog);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Ok(driverDayLog);
}
```

In WebApiConfig I have the following code

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter
        .SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Please guide me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Using `HttpClient` you don't have to serialize your object to Json before sending it to the Web Api. The `HttpClient` will take care of the serialization for you.

**Edit** (removed previous code that was apparently not working)

Instead of sending the Json in `PostAsJsonAsync`, simply send the object.

```
driverDayLogModel driverDayLog = new driverDayLogModel
{
    driverId = Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text),
    dayStartTime = DateTime.Now,
};
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:54314/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    // simply put the object as the second parameter instead of a Json string
    var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/driverdaylogs", driverDayLog).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // Some Stuff
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error Code" +
        response.StatusCode + " : Message - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
    }
}
```

As a side note: Using `.Result` will block your code, so the recommended way is using `await` and `async`, but that is outside of the scope of this question/answer.

Comment: Same Error, Not Working, Can you please let me know how can I make it working

Comment: if you know the code in your answer has issues then you should sort that out. If this becomes the accepted answer, people will simply copy and paste it without even looking at the comments

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu Your comment is valid. However, because the OP had `.Result` in his code and that piece of code is not the cause of his problem, I did not change it. He may have valid reasons for having it in there. And since this answer is a reply to a very specific problem (and does not offer anything above what can be found in any basic tutorial) I doubt that many people will just copy it.

Comment: @HafizSiddiq I changed the code. If that is still not working, you can do some debugging and set a breakpoint at `if (!ModelState.IsValid)` and see whether `log` is null. If it's null then there is probably a problem with deserializing the Json and we have to investigate that.

Comment: @FlorianLim I have tried the edited way as well, the same error, the object is not being passed as well, yes there is a problem with deserialization of object, I would like to bring your kind consideration to the point that the json `"{\"driverId\":1,\"dayStartTime\":\"2019-03-03T21:44:15.1912313+05:00\"}"` is not valid, But I am unable to convert it to valid json `{"driverId":1,"dayStartTime":"2019-03-03T21:44:15.1912313+05:00"}`

Comment: @HafizSiddiq At what point is the invalid Json `"{\"driverId\":1,\"dayStartTime\":\"2019-03-03T21:44:15.1912313+05:00\"}"` generated? The built-in Json Converter (usually Newtonsoft Json.NET) that serializes the object should not cause this. If you see that in Visual Studio by using MouseOver that would explain it, because VS masks the `"` by using `\"`. You can verify if the generated Json is valid by using `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(pathToSomeTextfile, json);` and checking if that is ok.

Comment: I am talking that this is an invalid json for HttpClient

Comment: @HafizSiddiq Can you share the code for `driverDayLogModel` class?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Please check Edited Question, I think there may be an error in the API, and API server is not allowing the request.